Azure App Service Private Endpoint, returning 404
I'm trying to access my Azure App Service via a private endpoint within a Virtual Network using the private DNS name (eg, mywebapp.privatelink.azurewebsites.net). The DNS resolution works correctly, resolving to the private IP, but every HTTP request to the private endpoint returns a 404 Site Not Found error. Below, I outline the steps I've taken to reproduce the issue:
I have an Azure App Service that I'll call "mywebapp." The public URL works correctly, and when I run:
curl -I http://mywebapp.azurewebsites.net
I get the expected response:
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Content-Length: 145
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Date: Thu, DD Nov YYYY HH:MM:SS GMT
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, OPTIONS
Cache-Control: private
Location: /Account/Logon?ReturnUrl=%2f
Set-Cookie: omissis;Path=/;HttpOnly;Domain=mywebapp.azurewebsites.net
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=63072000; includeSubDomains
X-XSS-Protection: 1
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Referrer-Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin
Content-Security-Policy: omissis

The public endpoint works perfectly.
Now, I created a virtual network and a private endpoint. The private DNS zone is privatelink.azurewebsites.net. When I check the recordset, I deduce that the hostname to use is mywebapp.privatelink.azurewebsites.net.
From the Azure virtual network, I perform some tests:
I run:
nslookup mywebapp.privatelink.azurewebsites.net
And I get:
Server:         127.0.0.11
Address:        127.0.0.11#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   mywebapp.privatelink.azurewebsites.net
Address: 10.0.0.5

So far, everything seems fine. The DNS name resolves correctly, and the private IP is correct.
Next, I run:
curl -I http://mywebapp.privatelink.azurewebsites.net
But I get:
HTTP/1.1 404 Site Not Found
Content-Length: 2667
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html
Date: Thu, 28 Nov 2024 11:38:14 GMT

This is not what I expect. I've tried many different configurations to get a proper result, but I always end up with this 404 Site Not Found error.
Could someone help me troubleshoot this issue?

Are you sure it's http: and not https:?

Where did you get 10.0.0.5 from? Is that an A record you set-up yourself or is it a CNAME or Azure-managed resource-alias?

Why are you checking with http://mywebapp.privatelink.azurewebsites.net? It's just a private link URL of the app that traverses over the virtual network and a private link on the Microsoft backbone network, eliminating exposure from the public Internet. Try using http://mywebapp.azurewebsites.net instead.

Even if a private endpoint is registered, you'll continue using the "public" endpoint to get access to your app.
See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview-private-endpoint#dns for further information.
 After this DNS configuration, you can reach your app privately with the default name mywebapp.azurewebsites.net. You must use this name, because the default certificate is issued for *.azurewebsites.net.
If you want to connect to the private endpoint locally, you'll have to either edit your host file or use a P2S-VPN with a Azure DNS Private Resolver.
